# Rails 3: Put parameter validation into Controller for API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, validation

I'm currently developing an API for an old project that uses Rails 3.0.20

Unfortunately Rails 3 implemented the validation on the model layer, which they changed for Rails4 because usually those validations belong in the controller layer.

What would be the best way to move that validation into the controllers without modifying the models/including modules

Are there any gems out there that can do that? Like "strong_pramaters" for instance? The problem with that one is that I would have to modify the models and I would rather leave them as they are.

Or what would be the best approach to write your own custom validators that can be used in the controller?

Comment: Rails 4 does not move the validation into controller. They just check inside the controller if the given parameters are allowed.

Comment: Validations are still in the model for Rails 4, but they moved the models attributes to the controller.

Comment: strong_parameter gives you liberty to select what params you are allowing to be passed to model. And the model validations works as earlier they make sure the integrity of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 4 uses strong parameters https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters which you can also use in a Rails 3 project, you just have to use the strong_parameters gem

This Railscast might be helpful for you http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters

EDIT

You can leave your model logic intact and skip the mass assignment check in the controller using the :without_protection => true option as documented here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class

Also you can conditionally run validations using :if and :unless (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) so you could set a property on your model like api_v2 and tack :unless => "api_v2" onto the validations you want to skip.  All you have to do is set that property to true in your controller.

Comment: Yup I already found that. The thing is the project has multiple API's. When I start messing around with the model parameter protection the other API's might not work anymore. Maybe I phrased my question wrong. What would be the best way to add parameter validation to the controller without touching the model? Just simple custom validators.

Comment: i was looking for validating request params and got here, strong parameters only check and allow parameters it doesn't doesn't let you check stuff like if value is greater than  or value is a string etc. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: the purpose of strong parameters is only to specify which fields can be modified NOT how they can be modified. Your talking about validation logic which belongs in the model, see here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html